# Is istio a bottleneck for Reactive applications?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

My Spring Boot App is deployed on Google Kubernetes Engine and has an Istio sidecar.

**Tech stack: Webflux (Spring boot 2.2.1), Istio, Kubernetes, Couchbase**

Whenever there is high load, the response time recorded in Stackdriver Tracing is **~1800ms**, whereas, the application logs indicate the entire operation was completed in the **~100ms** mark (verified by the complete() signal logged at the end).

> Thats a massive difference!!

The only layer in between my test JMeter deployed in another pod and my Spring Boot App is Istio.

I've tested my reactive app locally and its really fast and can take a lot of load. Can Istio be the bottleneck since its not reactive? Doesn't Istio work on a finite thread pool and follow a blocking and synchronous approach, i.e., non-reactive?

How can I debug this? Istio-proxy logs are reflecting roughly the time shown in Tracing.

**Does this mean the app is finishing fast but Istio is taking time to service the response? Please guide.**

Comment: Are you measuring application function Tracing against network requests? What component exactly is reporting `~100ms`? If this is network related, what are the local conditions? Given that a cluster has an intricate network scheme (specially when including Istio), it'd be expected to have some delay network-wise. Did the local test took that into consideration? You need to provide further details on what and how are you measuring.